# Asp.net Font File .otf file not found exception AddFontFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts

So I need to add a .otf font file to a PrivateFontCollection in c# using a font.otf file that is included in my project.  While the file loads locally, I receive the following exception when I deploy to my server.

**[Exception: Could not find font at path: D:\Inetpub\MyApplication\Content\Fonts\ProximaNovaAlt-Black.otf   The exception is: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: File not found.
   at System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection.AddFontFile(String filename)**

However when I look on the web server and navigate to that exact directory the file is there and is not read-only.

The font file is location in my project as follows
/Content/Fonts/ProximaNovaAlt-Black.otf

Also, the ProximaNovaAlt-Black.otf file's properties are as follows.
[image]

Finally, here is the code that is throwing the error

```
     public Font GetFont(float fontSize)
     {
       string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Content\Fonts\ProximaNovaAlt-Black.otf");

       try
       {

          PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
          privateFontCollection.AddFontFile(path);               

          return new Font(privateFontCollection.Families[0], fontSize);

          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {                   
             throw new Exception("Could not find font at path: " + path + "   The exception is: " +  ex.ToString());
          }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Add the font like a resources, then

```
PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();

var memory = IntPtr.Zero;

try
{
    memory = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(value.Length);

    Marshal.Copy(value, 0, memory, value.Length);
    privateFontCollection .AddMemoryFont(memory, value.Length);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(memory);
}

return new Font(privateFontCollection.Families[0], fontSize);
```

this work fine to me.

Comment: How do I initialize 'value' using this example

Comment: sorry, value is byte array, Resources.NameOfResource, when you add font as a resource you get back a byte array, hope this help.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria It doesn't work for me, still showing File not found exception. I tried for Proxima Nova otf fonts.

Answer (score 13):

FileNotFoundException is also the exception thrown if the font file is an unsupported type (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.addfontfile.aspx). TrueType fonts have good support, but there is only limited support for OpenType. And in my experience this seems to vary by platform.

I converted my OpenType fonts to TrueType using http://everythingfonts.com/otf-to-ttf and that solved the problem.

Comment: Would you expect this to happen if the development machine runs windows 8 (where the font works just fine) and the production machine runs server 2008?

Comment: Got the same error using the .ttf font file, file was on the server, the error showed that file could not be found.

Comment: +50 This was not the answer but turned out to be at least half the problem.

Comment: I am developing on windows 8 and when I deployed to window 2003 the OTF font would not load.  When I converted the OTF to a TTF using  http://everythingfonts.com/otf-to-ttf, it solved my problem also.

Answer (score 0):

Has windows encrypted the font folder on the server machine? I had that happen once. It was quite odd. Windows decided to encrypt the folder for funsies.

If the folder is encrypted, the folder name in windows explorer should be green rather than black.